# How to get some information about a random variable if we know very little about its distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, it.information-theory, trees

Suppose that $X, Y$ are random variables,both from a probability space to $(0,\infty]$, such that X and $1+Y$ have the same distribution, $Y=Z_1$ with  probability equals half, otherwise $Y= \frac{Z_1Z_2} {Z_1+Z_2}$ with  probability equals half and $Z_1,Z_2$ are iid and both are copies of $X$.

what can be said about $X$?is $X$ finite almost sure?what about $E(X),Var(X)$?

what i've tried:
$E(X)=1+E(Y)=1+\frac{1}{2}E(Z_1)+\frac{1}{2}E(\frac{Z_1Z_2} {Z_1+Z_2})$,
because $E(X)=E(Z_1)$,we get $E(X)=2+ E(\frac{Z_1Z_2} {Z_1+Z_2})$.

So $E(X-\frac{Z_1Z_2} {Z_1+Z_2})=2$,it is finite.Therefore $X-\frac{Z_1Z_2} {Z_1+Z_2}$ is almost sure finite.but what about $X$?

Is there any hint how to understand $X$?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the statement  *when $Y=Z_1$ or $Y=\frac{Z_1Z_2}{Z_1+Z_2}$ with   equal probability ...*

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu with probability=0.5 we have $Y=Z$ else $Y$ equals the fraction.

Comment: You need to formulate the first paragraph more  precisely.    As is I cannot make any sense.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu others have understood it.u can see:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891967/how-to-get-some-information-about-a-random-variable-if-we-know-sth-about-its-dis

Comment: Please  formulate the first paragraph precisely  This is a research level site and precision is expected in questions.  Precision in formulation also   increases the chance that you will get a meaningful answer.  I am confused by the word *when*. Does it stand for a conditional *if* ?  Is  it a substitute for a logical *AND*?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu i edited it.

Comment: Tell me if I  understand the assumptions. From what you wrote I understand two things. 1) $P(X<r)=P(Y<r-1)$, $\forall r\in\mathbb{R}$.   2) $P(Y=Z_1)=P(Y=Z_1Z_2/(Z+1+Z_2)=1/2$. Do you know anything else about the events $A_1=\{Y=Z_1\}$ and $A_2=\{Y=Z_1Z_2/(Z_1+Z_2)\}$. The word  *otherwise* that you use seems to imply that they are complementary. Is this the case?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu yes right.and Z_i 's are iid

Comment: Well, to start with, nothing that is written prevents you from having everything identically $+\infty$. On the other hand, if you assume that everything is finite a.s., do you have a single example satisfying such crazy set of properties? Or is it exactly the opposite, i.e., you got the properties from some external considerations and now wonder what the object might possibly be?

Comment: It would help if you add some context to your question?  More precisely I think you  should describe the original problem that led you to these conditions.